# SQL query to update a column(multiple rows) in a table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose there is a column in a table with NULL values with 'n' rows. Now I want to update that column with the values from another table column with same number of rows (n). How?

Edit:
My tables are: A and B, A has call_id, operator with 10 rows. call_id is primary key there. Now, B has call_id, calllog_id and duration as columns where call_id is FK and calllog_id is PK, In B, call_id is null in every row (same 10 rows). Now i want to copy the 10 row values of A.call_id into B.call_id

Comment: Please provide some reference to table structure , sample data and what is common between two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is a id column in both tables that you can join and you only want to update rows with NULL values in col_a of table_a

```
UPDATE A
SET A.col_a = B.col_b
FROM table_a A
JOIN table_b B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.col_a IS NULL
```

Comment: My tables are: A and B, A has call_id, operator with 10 rows. call_id is primary key there. Now, B has call_id, calllog_id and duration as columns where call_id is FK and calllog_id is PK, In B, call_id is null in every row (same 10 rows). Now i want to copy the 10 row values of A.call_id into B.call_id

Comment: You table only has 10 rows ? how do you associate which call_id value in table B needs to go to call_id in table A . Is there a connection of call_id and calllog_id like prefix or something.

Comment: No, there are more than 10 rows. And both the tables have same rows. I want to just copy the first row's call_id in A to first row of B. Like that. i th row call_id of A should be in ith row call_id of B

Comment: How do you define first row ?  can you show some sample data of table A and table B

Comment: A: call_id - 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 operator - airtel something something......... Now B: calllog_id - 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 call_id - null (7 times)..... I want fill these nulls with 10 12 14 16 18 20 22!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `join` with a generated sequential number:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col order by col) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
      where t1.col is null
     )
update toupdate
    set col = o.othercol
    from toupdate join
         (select o.*, row_numer() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
          from othertable o
         ) o
         on o.seqnum = toupdate.seqnum;
```